# Wordpress custom post type pagination shows same content on each page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a custom post type name portfolio.
I have applied pagination successfully but content on each page is the same.
Below is my code.
I have tried too many solutions but unable to find appropriate answer.
please help

```
<?php
$exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
'posts_per_page'=>10,
'post_type' => 'portfolio',
'job_role'  => 'executive',
'post-thumbnails' => 'thumbnail',
'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) );

 // The Loop

 if ( $exec_query->have_posts() ) { 
while ( $exec_query->have_posts() ): $exec_query->the_post(); ?>

<div>
// The content
</div>


<?php

endwhile; 
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $exec_query->max_num_pages
) );
wp_reset_postdata();

}

?>
```

Comment: Can you post the url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```html
$the_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>10,
                                 'post_type'=>'phcl',                                     
                                 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) 
                            ); 
                            ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-xs-12 file">
<a href="<?php echo $file; ?>" class="file-title" target="_blank">
<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
</a>
<div class="file-description"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
</div>
<?php
endwhile;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
 echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: yours and my code is almost same, can you tell me where is the difference. btw it didn't work

Comment: @fatima - please check again

Comment: i get it fixed but now it is not moving to page 3. i have almost to many posts but it does not load more than 2 pages

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    /*
    Template name: Test portfolio
    */
    $exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
    'posts_per_page'=>10,
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'job_role'  => 'executive',
    'post-thumbnails' => 'thumbnail',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) );

     if ( $exec_query->have_posts() ) { 

    while ( $exec_query->have_posts() ): $exec_query->the_post(); ?>

        <p><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></p>

        <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php

    endwhile; 


    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $exec_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
    wp_reset_postdata();

    }
?>
```

Comment: this is also the same code as mine. it did not worked.

Comment: checkout your portfolio content